# If statement that detects a class among multiple ones

Tags: javascript, if-statement, equality

I have this simple if statement:

```
if(comments.className === "hide")
```

However the class of the element I am trying to "select" is `class="hide slide"` and this doesn't seem to work if this is the case.
How would I write this so that he "finds" the hide among the 2 classes?

Comment: Is jQuery available? This type of thing is trivial with the big jQ.

Comment: @AD7six: Doh! I misread thesystem's comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split` and loop over it (or use [kennebec and Dogbert's elegant Regex solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15207847/157247), it will also work for any edge cases):

```
var parts = comments.className.split(" ");
var hasHide = false;
for (var i=0;i<parts.length;i++){
   if (parts[i] == "hide"){
      hasHide = true;
   }
}
if (hasHide){
   //...
}
```

Or use jQuery:

```
   if ($(comments).hasClass("hide")){
      //...
   }
```

Comment: Your split will work in most cases, but it'll be safer with a regex since the class separator can be one of many different types of whitespace, including tabs or line breaks.

Comment: And Chrome, at least, does *not* convert them to spaces: http://jsbin.com/ihaxek/1

Comment: @thesystem You're two are right, it's more reliable to use regex. Still, normally you'll be just fine checking for spaces, especially if you generate the Html code yourself.

Comment: @Matt: Yeah, I think it would be rare for someone to use something other than a space character. But could be a tough bug to track down if a tab makes it in there by accident.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `comments.className.split(/\s+/);` and then iterate over the options to find what you want

```
var classes = comments.className.split(/\s+/);
var classexists = false;
for(i=0; i<classes.length; i++){
    if(classes[i] === "specifiedclass"){
        classexists = true;
        break;
    }
if(classexists){...
```

#### Doing this as a function

```
function hasClass(desiredClass,el){
  var classes = el.className.split(/\s+/);
    var classexists = false;
    for(i=0; i<classes.length; i++){
        if(classes[i] === desiredClass){
            classexists = true;
            break;
        }
    }
   return classexists;
}
if(hasClass("specifiedclass",comments){...
```

(thanks to `the system` for the suggestion)

Comment: +1, Would be nice to make it reusable in a function that does a `return true` if the class is found, otherwise a `return false` at the end.

Comment: good point, edit coming.

Answer (score 2):

dogberts solution(removed) would be better if he tests for 'hide' with a possible space or start or end markers-

```
if(/(^|\s)hide(\s|$)/.test(comments.className))
```

Comment: What about non-space delimiters? (Tab, line break...) Chrome, at least, does *not* normalize those to spaces: http://jsbin.com/ihaxek/1 (I was kind of hoping it -- and the others -- would, but it's probably best that they don't.)

Comment: @TJ- I had to check, you are correct. (I never broke up a classname with newlines before). Edited my answer, thanks.

Comment: @ kennebec: *"I had to check"* Yeah, me too. :-)

Comment: If, as in this case, one *knows* that the class name contains no word-boundary characters (notably "-"), then shouldn't `\b` work? (As in `/\bhide\b/` ?)

Comment: @Pointy- you also have to know that there are no possible classnames with word boundaries, or you'll match dont-hide and hide-never as well as hide.Better safe...